# order by desc not shows in the correct order

Tags: mysql

I have a chat service, so:

```
select k.user, c.id, c.from, c.sent, c.message, c.recd from chat c
inner join cadastro k on c.from=k.id
where (`from`=? and `to`=?)
order by c.id
limit 50
```

I want to show the last 50 messages, if I send 1 to 100 it will show:

```
1
2
3
...
49
50
```

**I want to show the last 50 messages like this:**

```
50
51
...
100
```

if I put `order by c.id desc` it give me the order:

```
50
49
...
4
3
2
1
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select * from
(
  select k.user, c.id, c.from, c.sent, c.message, c.recd from chat c
  inner join cadastro k on c.from=k.id
  where (`from`=? and `to`=?)
  order by c.id desc
  limit 50
) tmp
order by id asc
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it's the most efficient way to do this, but you could try:

```
SELECT A.user, A.id, A.from, A.sent, A.message, A.recd
FROM (
   select TOP 50 k.user, c.id, c.from, c.sent, c.message, c.recd from chat c
   inner join cadastro k on c.from=k.id
   where (`from`=? and `to`=?)
   order by c.id DESC
) AS A
ORDER BY c.id ASC
```

Comment: Ah, I see juergen d beat me to the punch, nevermind then.